# How to Concatenate Integer and print it reversed in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, concatenation

I have a piece of code, a loop where an integer variable gets updated on each iteration. I wish to add the value of the variable one after the other after storing it into another variable of type string. And then reverse the string before finally printing it at the end.

```
>     for example:
>     
>     the loop gives an output say 1, 2, 3, 4... and so on.. on each iteration.
>     then, I want to have a string of value "1234"
>     and then reverse it to finally print "4321"
```

Comment: And you have tried?

Comment: You need three operations for that: converting an int to a string, adding two strings together, and reversing a string. Type all 3 separate into google, see what pops out, combine.

Comment: Have not tried anything specific. have tried explicit conversion to string from integer and then string concatenation each time inside the loop, but haven't been successful as of yet.

Comment: "I wish to ..." good for you! But what is your question?

Comment: *haven't been successful as of yet* - so where's your code that didn't work? What did it return instead of the expected output?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not code writing service

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you know exactly what you want. 
Google the pieces of code you need, and you'll get there.

**Appending an int to a string**

Use std::to_string(int variable) to convert the int to a string if you are using c++11. Otherwise, use a stringstream.

Once you've converted the int to a string, simply add it to the end of your string with numbers by doing

```
std::string str="";
for ...
  str += std::to_string(intVar);
```

**Reverse the string**

Using std::string, there is a reverse function.

```
std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Then simply print the results with

```
printf("%s\n", str.c_str());
```